# Does the angle between adjacent maxima remain the same?

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction, superposition

[image]

Is the angle between adjacent maxima, in this case adjacent rainbows, the same. That is, is the angle made by the First-order rainbow and Central white the same as the angle made by the First-order rainbow and the Second-order rainbow?
P.S: This is a diffraction grating and my question refers to the interference pattern  produced when monochromatic light is passed through a diffraction grating.

Comment: Are you familiar with the grating equation?

Comment: No and in some cases you can have overlap of orders.

Comment: Are you asking about a diffraction grating? The only mention of diffraction is in the tags. Your question mentions rainbows which are not caused by diffraction.

Comment: @Semoi Yes I am

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes, I am talking about diffraction gratings and the interference pattern produced by diffraction gratings.